# Metamask account related to Geth account?

Tags: password, import

I've created a Metamask account and now I want to import it to Geth. I don't have a Geth account. I've exported the private key to a .txt file. When I import the file Geth asks me to insert 2 times the passphrase. The question is, do I have to put the same password (Metamask) or create a new one? Is it the same account?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It needn't be the same.

It'll be a password for unlocking accessing the private key locally.